# Delphi CGI SQL query runs on one machine but not the other

Tags: sql-server, delphi, iis, cgi

I have a console app running queries to a SQL Server. The SQL Server and the website are running on the same server (colocation). I have an image of the website on my local machine where a copy of the app runs  connecting to the same SQL Server. The app will return the result of a SQL query from a text submission via a form:

```
<TEXTAREA id="SQL" ROWS=8 COLS=80></TEXTAREA>
<p>
<button onclick="submit()">&nbsp;Execute&nbsp;</button></p>
```

Example 1:

```
select * from table1
```

Running this on my local website or on the server will return the correct result.

Example 2:

```
select column1, column2 from table1
```

On my local website I get the proper result, on the server I get

> server error 403 access forbidden

Local machine runs Abyss while server runs IIS. The console app makes requests to the SQL Server via the VPN wether it is running on my machine or on the server.

Both app instances use the same connection string. I tried to modify the server version by using the localhost IP (127.0.0.1) instead of the VPN IP but results were the same.

Comment: IIS doesn't come with CGI enabled by default. Have you gone into Server Manager and installed CGI? Ref: [CGI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/cgi)

Comment: Please check the Windows Event Viewer log for more detailed error information.

Comment: Check the IIS logs on the server for more details about the 403 error and check the substatus code. The logs may provide additional information about why the server rejected the request.